# Kafka Streams API pushes old values to a topic only after a new event arrives

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have surfed the internet for some time before writing the question, and it seems that this problem is not so much popular (not a mention of it anywhere). I use Kafka Streams API in my project for a calculation of something. I won't go into details of the algorithm, because it is not important here at all, what I have a problem with is that old values that are to be pushed to the topic are not pushed there until new values arrive. I guess it is because I use windowing and suspend the window, but I would like to somehow solve the problem (not with hacky solutions like pushing empty events). In this particular case, I need to wait till the end of the window before publishing the value to the output topic. The topology looks as follows:

```
firstStream.leftJoin(secondStream, ...)
    .leftJoin(thirdStream, ...)
    .filter(...)
    .groupByKey(...)
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(windowSeconds)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(graceSeconds)))
    .aggregate(...)
    .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))
    .toStream()
    .to(outputTopic)
```

So, whenever I push an event to the `firstStream`, I should receive an output of the transformations in the `outputTopic` after the window closes, but actually, I receive the output only when I push a new event after the window closes.
So, my question is whether there is a way to push output after the window closes without sending a new event?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `joins` in general, but I think your problem relates to what you think `suppress` does. I assume you're using stream time notion, which practically means your stream does not advance until the stream has received new events. If you don't care about producing intermediate results, you can stop using `suppress`. Consider reading this excellent [Confluent blogpost](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/), specifically the chapter called "What time is it?
"

Comment: I guessed that this happens due to `.suppress`, but this behavior is pretty interesting. Usually, the purpose of suppress is to wait until some point and then push, not to wait for some point, receive an event, and push then. 
I really need to wait until the end of the window, intermediate results will ruin the logic of the whole operation.